# Store GMP/MPIR numbers in a QList

Tags: qt4, gmp, qlist

I am trying to write a program in C++ with QT4.7 and the MPIR library (v. 2.3.1). 
During some calculations, I need to store a dynamic amount of mpz_t (the integer storage type) and want to use a QList or QVarLengthArray for that. I have successfuly set up a basic test on how to do that, but it looks so ugly and plain wrong that I want to ask for a better to do this.

My sample program:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QList>
#include <qtimer.h>
#include <mpirxx.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QList<__mpz_struct> test;

    std::cout << "Write ints 0 to 9 in the QList" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        mpz_t zahl;
        mpz_init_set_si(zahl, i);
        test.append(zahl[0]);
    }

    std::cout << "Check if everything is still there." << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        mpz_t zahl;
        zahl[0] = test.at(i);
        std::cout << mpz_get_str(NULL, 10, zahl) << std::endl;  
    }
    std::cout << "What an ugly hack." << std::endl;

    QTimer::singleShot(0, &a, SLOT(quit()));
    return a.exec();
}
```

(compiled under Windows 7/MSVC2010 SP1/QT4.7.3/MPIR2.3.1)
The output is correct, but I doubt it is a valid or even safe way to store mpz_t.

Please let me know how to achieve this :)

Comment: Why do you think its not safe?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be using your stored data in lots of places, passing it between function, etc. then I would definitely use a QList as they are [implicitly shared](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/implicit-sharing.html#implicitly-shared).

This allows for many nice things like the following:

```
void listOperation(QList<mpz_t> list)
{
    // Initialize and set
    mpz_t an_int;
    mpz_init_set_si(an_int, 0);
    list.append(an_int);
}
```

In this code we are passing 'list' by value, so normally a deep copy (duplicating all data) would occur. However, because of the implicit sharing only a shallow copy (reference copy; pointer to a shared data block) occurs. Additionally, even if this function were to get called very frequently, a QList preallocates extra space on both sides of its internal buffer, so this operation will usually be O(1) (Taken from the [QList](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlist.html#append)) documentation.

A QList (and all of QT's container classes) are just like std containers--they can hold objects of any type (even primitives, and pointers).

This gets tricky when using GMP for two reasons.

1. mpz_t types are pointer like, but you can't use new
2. mpz_clear is used in cleanup

A better approach would probably be to use the [class interface](http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-Integers.html#C_002b_002b-Interface-Integers). That way you can allocate your mpz_t objects as mpz_class objects in the typical c++ fashion, and not have to worry about things.

```
mpz_class an_int = 1234;
mpz_class *another = new mpz_class(1234);
```

**Updated example:**
(Not compiled/ tested)

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>
#include <qtimer.h>
#include <mpirxx.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QList<mpz_class *> list;

    qdebug() << "Write ints 0 to 9 in the QList";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        test.append(new mpz_class(0));
    }

    qdebug() << "Check if everything is still there.";
    foreach (mpz_class *item, list)
    {
        qdebug() << *item;
    }
    qdebug() << "Not so bad anymore.";

    // Clean up list
    qDeleteAll(list.begin(), list.end());
    list.clear();        

    QTimer::singleShot(0, &a, SLOT(quit()));
    return a.exec();
}
```